# Getting Gitlab API data in a simple node/react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, curl, gitlab-api

Basically, I'm having a hard time pulling data from Gitlab to a simple node/react app.

I got this CURL API link from Gitlab API docs:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: S3x4***RJ" "https://git.mywebsite.com/api/v4/projects/1212/boards"`

and when I use it in terminal, nicely gives me all the data that I need:

```
  {
    "id": 111,
    "name": "Jimmy",
    "username": "JSmith",
    "state": "active",
    "avatar_url": "https://git.mywebsite.com/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/111/avatar.png",
    "web_url": "https://git.mywebsite.com/JSmith"
  },
  {
    "id": 223,
    "name": "Billy Dean",
    "username": "BDean",
    "state": "active",
    "avatar_url": "https://git.mywebsite.com/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/223/avatar.png",
    "web_url": "https://git.mywebsite.com/BDean"
  }
```

etc.

**But how should my .js look like, with this CURL API implementation, in order to get variables like containing "id" or "state" data?**

I tried converting this CURL with https://curl.trillworks.com/#node

After implementing it like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {PageHeader} from "antd";
import * as util from "util"; // All Resources

const api = new Gitlab({
    host: 'https://git.mywebsite.com',
    token: 'S3x4***_hXxRJ',
});

// Listing users
let users = api.Users

// Or using Promise-Then notation
api.Projects.all().then((projects) => {
    console.log(projects);
});
console.log(util.inspect(users, false, null));
alert(util.inspect(users, false, null));


class AgileMetrics extends React.Component {


    componentDidMount() {
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PageHeader
                    className="site-page-header"
                    title="Metrics"
                    subTitle="Get an overview on the Metrics here..."
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Metrics;
```

... all I got was my connection information:

[image]

I also tried the [Gitbreaker](https://github.com/jdalrymple/gitbeaker) library, using it as in their examples.
Maybe using their examples, I miss adding something else, which is obvious to an experienced person.

Comment: what is `util.inspect`?

Comment: Also, where `Gitlab` package are you using to make the calls? `gitbeaker` - https://github.com/jdalrymple/gitbeaker#readme?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are assigning `users` to just the users api function in the Gitlab package. And assuming your `utils` function extracts the data that you want like `id`, `state` - since it's just assigned the raw function, it's rendering that.

Maybe something like this?

```
// https://github.com/jdalrymple/gitbeaker#readme
import { Gitlab, Projects, Users } from '@gitbeaker/browser'; 
// .. add other imports

// initialize the api with credentials
const api = new Gitlab({
    host: 'https://git.mywebsite.com',
    token: 'S3x4***_hXxRJ',
});

class AgileMetrics extends React.Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
      const projects = await Projects.all()
      const users = await Users.all()

      // process `users` with `utils.inspect`
      console.log(users)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PageHeader
                    className="site-page-header"
                    title="Metrics"
                    subTitle="Get an overview on the Metrics here..."
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, nothing happens, and I get an error: `'api' is assigned a value but never used` (same for `projects`, but that's more obvious)